# Access all LDAP group names

Tags: java, security, permissions, spring-security, ldap

My application allows to create custom entities(Objects) using web-interface. I need to assign permissions(authorization) to users/groups (that are available in LDAP) on these custom entities. e.g. a user-group grp1 can access custom entity ent1, but group grp2 cannot access ent1.
Since these entities are created dynamically, I need some mechanism to access the LDAP groups to map the permissions for a group to an entity at run-time.

My implementation platform is JEE and/or Spring. What are my options? Do I get some solution out-of-box? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#introduction) is everything that you'll need. I use Spring with LDAP and it work's fine. Specially using **ldap-template** that do much things for you including a work around in the *PartialResultException*. Read the documentation, you won't regret